# Matplotlib surface plot, MemoryError. Data in three columns

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a big data file containing 3 columns for x, y, z (1,6M x 3 array, 128 MB). I was trying to produce a contourf plot in Matplotlib, but when transforming the data for X,Y grid, I have run out of memory, which was of course very likely to happen.
Here is an example script (I have also tried other numpy/scipy methods for interpolation, but the same MemoryError):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
a=np.loadtxt("data.dat")
xi = np.linspace(min(a[:,0]), max(a[:,0]), 40000)
yi = np.linspace(min(a[:,1]), max(a[:,1]), 40000)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(a[:,0], a[:,1], a[:,2], xi, yi, interp='nearest')
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

So I tried to use MATLAB for the same procedure and in the end, either I would have to use a very small matrix for interpolation, thus losing a picture that I was interested to obtain (data show quite fast oscillations). Here is a MATLAB script (variable "a" also represents the data array):

```
x1=a(:,1);
y1=a(:,2);
z1=a(:,3);
xi=linspace(min(x1),max(x1),40000);
yi=linspace(min(y1),max(y1),40000);
[XI YI]=meshgrid(xi,yi);
ZI = griddata(x1,y1,z1,XI,YI,'nearest');
contourf(XI,YI,ZI)
```

Obviously, it looks the same as in Python :)
Just to show that it is feasible to get what I want, a result from Origin is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlwHU.png)

None of the solutions which I found on the web worked for my problem.